# prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to change the below mysql to mysqli(prepared statements) but I got stuck at it.

**The problem:** `Warning: mysqli_stmt
::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement` This error occurs at $get_empty_field = $ok->bind_result($username, $firstname, $lastname); line. I am not done with the conversion, I just did what I could and left the rest as it was.(I am not mixing mysql and mysqli)

**Mysql query**

```
$check_added_files = mysql_query("select * from `vpb_uploads` where `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."' and `firstname` = '' and `image_one` != '' and `image_two` != '' and `image_three` != '' and `image_four` != '' and `image_five` != ''");
                    if(mysql_num_rows($check_added_files) == 1)
                    {
                    echo 'up_to_five_already';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_to_upload']['tmp_name'], $final_uploads_location)) 
                    {
                    $check_empty_field = mysql_query("select * from `vpb_uploads` where `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($username))."'  and `firstname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string("")."' and `lastname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string("")."'");
                    if(mysql_num_rows($check_empty_field) < 1)
                    {
                    mysql_query("insert into `vpb_uploads` values('', '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."', '', '', '".mysql_real_escape_string($random_name_generated)."', '', '', '', '', '".mysql_real_escape_string(date("d-m-Y"))."')");

                    $identity = "image_one";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    $get_empty_field = mysql_fetch_array($check_empty_field);
                    $image_one = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_one"]);
                    $image_two = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_two"]);
                    $image_three = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_three"]);
                    $image_four = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_four"]);
                    $image_five = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_five"]);
                    global $identity;

                    if(empty($image_one))
                    {
                        mysql_query("update `vpb_uploads` set `image_one` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($random_name_generated)."' where `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($username))."' and `firstname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string("")."' and `lastname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string("")."'");

                        $identity = "image_one";

                    }
                    elseif(empty($image_two))
                    {
                        mysql_query("update `vpb_uploads` set `image_two` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($random_name_generated)."' where `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($username))."' and `firstname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string("")."' and `lastname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string("")."'");

                        $identity = "image_two";
                    }
                    elseif(empty($image_three))
                    {
                        mysql_query("update `vpb_uploads` set `image_three` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($random_name_generated)."' where `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($username))."' and `firstname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string("")."' and `lastname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string("")."'");

                        $identity = "image_three";
                    }
                    elseif(empty($image_four))
                    {
                        mysql_query("update `vpb_uploads` set `image_four` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($random_name_generated)."' where `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($username))."' and `firstname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string("")."' and `lastname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string("")."'");

                        $identity = "image_four";
                    }
                    elseif(empty($image_five))
                    {
                        mysql_query("update `vpb_uploads` set `image_five` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($random_name_generated)."' where `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($username))."' and `firstname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string("")."' and `lastname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string("")."'");

                        $identity = "image_five";
                    }
```

**WHAT I HAVE SO FAR:**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "newlogin");
                if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
                }


                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select * from `vpb_uploads` where `username` = ? and `firstname` = '' and `image_one` != '' and `image_two` != '' and `image_three` != '' and `image_four` != '' and `image_five` != ''");
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->store_result();

                if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {

                echo 'up_to_five_already';
                }


                else
                {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_to_upload']['tmp_name'], $final_uploads_location)) 
                {
                $firstname = "''";
                $lastname = "''";
                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select * from `vpb_uploads` where `username` = ?  and `firstname` = ? and `lastname` = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $firstname, $lastname);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->store_result();
                if ($stmt->num_rows < 1)

                {
                $date = 'date("d-m-Y")';
                $image_2 = "''";
                $image_3 = "''";
                $image_4 = "''";
                $image_5 = "''";
                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("insert into `vpb_uploads` (`username`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `image_one`, `image_two`, `image_three`, `image_four`, `image_five`, `date`) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                $stmt->bind_param('sssssssss',  $username, $firstname, $lastname, $random_name_generated, $image_2, $image_3, $image_4, $image_5, $date);
                $stmt->execute();


                $identity = "image_one";
                }
                else
                {

                $get_empty_field = $stmt->bind_result($username, $firstname, $lastname);
                $image_one = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_one"]);
                $image_two = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_two"]);
                $image_three = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_three"]);
                $image_four = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_four"]);
                $image_five = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_five"]);
                global $identity;

               if(empty($image_one))
                    {
                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("update `vpb_uploads` set `image_one` = ? where `username` = ? and `firstname` = ? and `lastname` = ? ");
                $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $random_name_generated, $username, $firstname, $lastname);    
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();

                $identity = "image_one";

                }
                elseif(empty($image_two))
                {
                mysql_query("update `vpb_uploads` set `image_two` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($random_name_generated)."' where `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($username))."' and `firstname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string("")."' and `lastname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string("")."'");

                $identity = "image_two";
                }
                elseif(empty($image_three))
                {
                mysql_query("update `vpb_uploads` set `image_three` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($random_name_generated)."' where `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($username))."' and `firstname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string("")."' and `lastname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string("")."'");

                $identity = "image_three";
                }
                elseif(empty($image_four))
                {
                mysql_query("update `vpb_uploads` set `image_four` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($random_name_generated)."' where `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($username))."' and `firstname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string("")."' and `lastname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string("")."'");

                $identity = "image_four";
                }
                elseif(empty($image_five))
                {
                mysql_query("update `vpb_uploads` set `image_five` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($random_name_generated)."' where `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($username))."' and `firstname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string("")."' and `lastname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string("")."'");

                $identity = "image_five";
                }
```

Comment: Can you tell us the exact line where the error occurs?

Comment: I am not done yet...I already stated that in the question..

Comment: Where does `$ok` comes from?

Comment: Instead of using `SELECT *` why not only select the columns that you need / bind?

Comment: @Jueecy sorry that was typo.

Comment: Duplicate of too localized http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663326/selecting-multiple-rows-mysqli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change your `SELECT` statement:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select `username`,`firstname`,`lastname` from `vpb_uploads` where `username` = ?  and `firstname` = ? and `lastname` = ?");
```

And you will need to fix the variable name:

```
$get_empty_field = $stmt->bind_result($username, $firstname, $lastname);
```

Comment: thanks that seems to solve the error. now have to deal with the rest. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[As I told you before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15663498/285587), you have to change to PDO, not mysqli.
Of course, just copying the code will do no good. You need at least connect to PDO first. There was a link to PDO tag wiki I provided, with complete connection code to copy. Also, aside form just copying the code, you need to spend some own efforts to make it work - at least by tweaking with your database settings.

In general, codes you get here are not intended to work out of the box. They are to give you an idea, make you learn. This is very important matter - you need to learn from answers, to be able to do the next similar work yourself. If you just copy and paste the code, you will ask  Stack Overflow to rewrite all your application then. Please, learn from answers and try to employ the knowledge you got.

Comment: I would change it to PDO if I knew how to do it. I did a google search and I kinda got confused. I might try PDO further if I got stuck again. Thanks anyway!

Comment: This is going to be an uphill battle in the next few years.

Comment: @joeframbach there is nothing to battle for. just click the link and compare the few lines I provided with couple of screens of toilsome code the OP struggles with.